# Angular 1.3 css animation not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular, I've pretty much copy pasted the example off the docs but I can't get it to work.
I've searched online but the examples I've come across are for older versions of angular...

Demo: [Plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qo2qCs7ipZc4mVykGi4n?p=preview)

html:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <button ng-click="shown = true">Fade in</button>
    <button ng-click="shown = false">Fade out</button>
    <p ng-if="shown" class="fade-in-animation">Hello!</p>
</body>
```

js:

```
angular.module('plunker', []).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.shown = false
});
```

css:

```
.fade-in-animation.ng-enter, .fade-in-animation.ng-leave {
    -webkit-transition:2s linear all;
    transition:2s linear all;
}

.fade-in-animation.ng-enter {opacity: 0;}
.fade-in-animation.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {opacity: 1;}
.fade-in-animation.ng-leave {opacity: 1;} 
.fade-in-animation.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {opacity: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to loading `angular-animate.js` you also need to add the `ngAnimate` module as a dependency.

In your case, instead of:

```
angular.module('plunker', [])
```

Do:

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ngAnimate'])
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/vkiuJDW9IHFianW1ZbbK?p=preview